# Mathematical formulation for index of the smallest element in a matrix

Tags: matrices, index-notation

I have a matrix $X$ with elements $x_{i,j}$ and need to identify the indices $(i',j')$ of the smallest element of the matrix.

From a coding perspective, this is not hard (writing in python I used numpy.where). However,  I do not know how to write in the paper the procedure down in a mathematically correct way.

For now, I simply wrote simply

$i',j' ~\text{ where }~ x_{i',j'}  = \min\left( X \right)$

but this seems odd to me.

Can somebody tell me a better way to formulate this mathematically correct (and if possible short)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(i',j')=\arg\min_{i,j} x_{i,j}$$

Comment: Thank you Rob, this was I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to explain your code is to use English. Just say

> $(i',j')$ is the index of the least entry in matrix $X$.

"Mathematically correct" does not require a formula. The words are  fine.

Comment: Usually, I would argue but in this specific case, it, unfortunately, does not work well. But never the less thank you very much.